# VBA infinite nested for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write nested for loops to loop through the rows of a column to do some calculation then go to the next column to do it again. The logic makes sense to me, but the output to the sheet flashes back and forth between the correct answers and overwriting everything with the same number, and it just keeps doing that. Please let me know if I need to clarify on anything, thanks in advance.

```
Sub findAvg2()
Dim maxVal As Double
Dim preHr As Double
Dim nextHr As Double
Dim cVal As Double
Dim pVal As Double
Dim nVal As Double
Dim avg As Double
Dim maxAvg As Double
Dim i As Integer 'row
Dim j As Integer 'col
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer

lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row                    'Find the number of rows in column A(1)
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 19 To lRow
    For j = 2 To lCol
        maxVal = Cells(2, j).Value
        preHr = Cells(8, j).Value
        nextHr = Cells(9, j).Value
        avg = (maxVal + preHr + nextHr) / 3
        If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
            pVal = Cells(i - 1, j).Value
            cVal = Cells(i, j).Value
            nVal = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            maxAvg = (pVal + cVal + nVal) / 3
            If avg > maxAvg Then
                maxAvg = avg
            End If
        End If
        Cells(12, j).Value = maxAvg
        'Debug.Print maxAvg
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: WElcome to SO. Your logic looks ok, but because there is not data example, can't test it. Try debugging your code. Execute it with F8 step by step, and see what happens in every iteration and why *....overwriting everything with the same number, and it just keeps doing that...*

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code and find nothing wrong with it. The modifications I did make appear to me to be of cosmetic nature. Here is the result.

```
Sub findAvg2()
    ' 005
    Dim maxVal As Double
    Dim preHr As Double
    Dim nextHr As Double
    Dim cVal As Double
    Dim pVal As Double
    Dim nVal As Double
    Dim Avg As Double
    Dim maxAvg As Double
    Dim Cl As Long                              ' last used column
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last used row
    Dim C As Long                               ' column
    Dim R As Long                               ' row

    ' Find the number of used columns and roaws in the sheet
    Cl = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For R = 19 To Rl
        For C = 2 To Cl
            maxVal = Cells(2, C).Value
            preHr = Cells(8, C).Value
            nextHr = Cells(9, C).Value
            maxAvg = (maxVal + preHr + nextHr) / 3

            cVal = Cells(R, C).Value
            If cVal > 0 Then
                pVal = Cells(R - 1, C).Value
                nVal = Cells(R + 1, C).Value
                Avg = (pVal + cVal + nVal) / 3
                If Avg > maxAvg Then maxAvg = Avg
            End If
            Cells(12, C).Value = maxAvg
            'Debug.Print maxAvg
        Next C
    Next R
End Sub
```

There is a possible weakness in this line of your code. `For R = 19 To Rl`. Since you are including the previous row in your calculation of averages row 18 must contain data. If it doesn't, and you can't exclude the first data row from evaluation, special provision must be made for the calculation of the initial maxAvg.

All action takes place on the ActiveSheet. This is an arrangement I instinctively dislike. Unless you are calling the sub from a button on that sheet - and even then, in case a smart alec wants to use F5 instead - I would name the sheet in the code. Use a CodeName both for greater security and to allow users the freedom to rename the sheet. This code will run on whatever sheet that happens to be active. It doesn't even have to be in the same workbook.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to check my code. I do realize that the line `For R = 19 to Rl` may cause trouble since the last line could contain data. For now, line 18 will almost always be 0. So I sort of just hard coded that part. But it is not good practice, I will fix that. After working more on this code, I realized that it could just be because it's such a huge amount of data, each cell were updating **very** slowly. So I wrote a function instead, with user input variables which made the program run almost instantly.

Comment: That sounds very good. If data volume is an issue consider reading the sheet into an array, values onlY, and worth with the array. You may have noticed that I already reduced some references to the sheet. That's slow.